# MYSQL UPDATE field with value of another field *and* using REPLACE in a prepared statement inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Initial Question (later on extended - see below):

Is it possible to update a field with a value from another field  and in that process replace a string inside that updated value?

I tried the following (very simplified):

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = REPLACE(field2, string1, string2);
```

Example: `field2` contains "dark blue", `string1` is "blue", `string2` is "red".

I expected all values from `field2` to be copied to `field1`, but while copying replace any instance of `string1` to be replaced by `string2` in `field1`. So in my example the value of `field2` should become "dark red".

But that only copied the unaltered values of `field2` into `field1`, without any replacement / change. (in my example `field2` becomes "dark blue")

---

EDIT / ADDITION:

The fiddles which @axiac and @2SRTVF created and linked to in their comments showed me that the code I posted actually DOES work. Thank you both very much!

However, my *original* code is embedded in a prepared statement. Also the prepared statement alone works as expected. But that prepared statement is inside a `foreach` loop which runs through an array, and in that situation the update query doesn't work...

Here is the code I actually use:

```
$db = new mysqli("my_host", "my_user", "my_pw", "my_database");

foreach($my_array AS $x=>$y) {
  if($ps = $db->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET field1 = REPLACE(field2, ?, ?) ")) {
    $ps->bind_param("ss", $x, $y);
    $ps->execute();
    $ps->close();
  }
}
```

The array contains key/value pairs, one of them in my above example would be `blue / red`.

Comment: The query you posted should work. Check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6115e2/1 Make sure `string1` is present in `field2` and mind the capitalization. [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) is case sensitive.

Comment: @Johannes Can you please tell what you want as final values for field1 and field2?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a3996084644b34ce497b5c7c2116f49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your loop. All of the replacements that happen in the first `count($my_array)-1` passes through the loop are thrown away by the last pass because the `UPDATE` is always copying from the current value of `field2`, not the (possibly) previously modified copy of `field1`. Try adding this before the loop:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = field2
```

and then change the query in the loop to:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = REPLACE(field1, ?, ?)
```

Note that by preparing the query in the loop you are losing the efficiency benefit of prepared queries. It would be better to write it as:

```
if ($ps = $db->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET field1 = REPLACE(field1, ?, ?) ")) {
    foreach ($my_array as $x => $y) {
        $ps->bind_param("ss", $x, $y);
        $ps->execute();
    }
    $ps->close();
}
```

So if for example your table contains

```
field1  field2
x       dark blue
y       light green
```

and `$my_array = array('blue' => 'red', 'green' => 'pink')` then after running this code you will get:

```
field1      field2
dark red    dark blue
light pink  light green
```

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right.  What you can do is:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = field2, field2 = REPLACE(field2, string1, string2);
```

Comment: The OP asks how to modify the value of `field1`. `field2` must not be modified.

Comment: I don't think so. He is saying, field2 should become dark red.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case (see addition to question above)